# PhP Making array of date ranges as key - getting unexpected output

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of the `YYYY/MM` as the key and just 0 as the value (going to be doing replacing later in my code) from the past year. The current code I have it getting a really weird output. Maybe I am using `range()` improperly? I've never used this function until today.

```
$start_date = date('Y/m');
$end_date = date('Y/m', strtotime("-1 year"));
$past_year = array(); 
foreach (range($startDate, $endDate) as $year) :
   $past_year[$year] = 0;
endforeach;
```

For some reason after running this code, the `$past_year` array just has

```
print_r($past_year);
Array ( [2] => 0 );
```

I'm looking to get back

```
Array(
 '2016/01' => 0,
 '2016/02' => 0,
 '2016/03' => 0,
 '2016/04' => 0,
 '2016/05' => 0,
 '2016/06' => 0,
 '2016/07' => 0,
 '2016/08' => 0,
 '2016/09' => 0,
 '2016/10' => 0,
 '2016/11' => 0,
 '2016/12' => 0,
 '2017/01' => 0,
);
```

Any suggestions on how I cant get that output?

Comment: `$startDate` !== `$start_date`; `$endDate` !== `$end_date`

Comment: Why do you thing that `range()` creates DATE ranges ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate your dates. Using the DateTIme class and DateInterval class makes it really easy.

```
$end = new DateTime();
$begin = (new DateTime())->modify('-1 year');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$past_year = [];

foreach ($period as $date) {
    $past_year[$date->format('Y/m')] = 0;
}

print_r($past_year);
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [2016/01] => 0
    [2016/02] => 0
    [2016/03] => 0
    [2016/04] => 0
    [2016/05] => 0
    [2016/06] => 0
    [2016/07] => 0
    [2016/08] => 0
    [2016/09] => 0
    [2016/10] => 0
    [2016/11] => 0
    [2016/12] => 0
)
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!